# Entity Framework Fluent API ICollection.count (one to many)

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am new to EF and i have the following scenario:

I want to load the IHave apples without loading the whole Apples collection.

The model:

```
public class Category
{
  public virtual ICollection<Classified> Apples { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public bool IHaveApples {get { return Apples.count > 0; } }      
}
```

And the FLUENT API Config:

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
    public CategoryConfiguration()
    {
      HasMany(o => o.Apples ).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(o => o.CategoryId);
    }
}
```

And in my controller i go with

```
//The controller returns IQueryable<Category>
var category = _contextProvider.Context.Categories;
```

Thanks in advance,
Stelios K.

Answer (score 0):

As `IHaveApples` is a `bool`, you should simply use `Apples.Any()` instead of `Count`.

---

EDIT:

If you want this to be automatically set (i.e. the boolean is set without even accessing manually to your collection), what you could do is add an handler to the [`ObjectMaterialized`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event:

```
public class Category
{
    ...
    public bool IHaveApples { get; set; }
}

((IObjectContextAdapter)yourDbContext).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var entityAsCategory = e.Entity as Category;
        if (entityAsCategory != null)
        {
            entityAsCategory.IHaveApples = yourDbContext
                .Entry(entityAsCategory)
                .Collection(z => z.Apples)
                .Query()
                .Any();
        }
    };
```

Comment: True, but the thing is that either count or any, aren't gonna be lazy loaded?

I want when (var category = _contextProvider.Context.Categories;) is called the property to be setted immediately.

(The code misses the setter..my bad)

Comment: However i get a second datareader while the first has not be closed..
Checking it now.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't the correct case to use this solution..
The DataReader will remain open till the object is materialized.

Also the purpose to open a second datareader is not performant since the same operation could be performed in a single query..

Either i need to edit the CategoryConfiguration (don't know how), or write a custom query